# Read and query SQLite database using sqldf

Tags: database, r, sqlite, select, sqldf

I have a SQLite database `pisa06.db` created from a data frame. I would like to read variables (columns) from this database file selectively without actually loading into memory. I know I can do it with a data frame already in the workspace. I couldn't figured out how to do it with a database in the disk without reading the whole database.

Let me give you more detail. I have a data frame `pisa06`. I created a database file `pisa06.db` in the working directory with

```
library(sqldf)
drv <- dbDriver("SQLite") 
con <- dbConnect(drv, "pisa06.db") 
dbWriteTable(con, "pisa06", pisa06)
```

Now I need to reach this database file and read some variables into a data frame without reading the whole database. I have tried many alternatives. This will not work:

```
df <- sqldf("select CNT, SCHOOLID from pisa06", drv="SQLite")
```

How can I use `sqldf`for this purpose? Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `RSQLite` package:

```
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "pisa06.db")
dbGetQuery(con,"select CNT, SCHOOLID from pisa06")
```